# StructureMap: Programmatically retrieve list of instance keys from StructureMap.config

Tags: .net, structuremap

I've defined a  for a specific interface within my StructureMap.config. There can be many different available concrete types defined.

I would like to programmatically retrieve a list of available instance keys (names) that are currently available without actually parsing the StructureMap.config file itself. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can inspect the container using its Model property.

For example, the following code will print the names of all instances of IWidget:

```
foreach(var instance in container.Model.InstancesOf<IWidget>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(instance.Name);
}
```